# Finding nearest square in python using - for loop

Tags: python

I wrote a program to ***find the nearest square in python*** using while loop, which goes like the below:

```
num = 0
while (num+1)**2 < limit:
    num += 1
nearest_square = num**2
print(nearest_square)
```

This made me wonder, if we can find the same using a for loop.
I am unable to understand how can we set the range of the same.

Can anyone please guide?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best way to find the nearest square.

```
int(limit ** (0.5)) ** 2
```

If `limit = 200` then the output is `196`.

But if you want to do the exact same thing you did above using `for` loop use this,

```
for num in range(limit + 1):
  if (num + 1) ** 2 >= limit:
    break
```